# Sum timecodes in array, using only reduce

Tags: javascript

I have got an array with timecodes, it's look like this: `["5:43", "2:33", "3:45", "0:47", "5:21", "6:56", "3:46", "5:25", "3:14", "3:31", "5:59", "3:07", "11:29", "8:57", "5:49", "5:52", "5:50", "9:13", "11:51", "7:58", "4:40", "4:45", "6:46", "7:24", "7:12", "5:23", "3:34", "8:22", "5:17", "3:10", "4:43", "19:43", "0:47", "0:47", "3:14", "3:59", "2:43", "4:17", "6:56", "3:05", "2:06", "1:59", "1:49", "3:36", "7:10", "3:44", "3:44", "4:36", "3:16", "1:10", "6:10", "2:14", "3:44", "5:05", "6:03", "12:39", "1:56", "4:04"]`.
I need to sum seconds inside an array, by one reduce method.

Var *timer* gives me the right list of numbers, which I need to sum. For some reason, it doesn't want to sum it by itself. If I make the timer var an array and push things inside - they have no indexes, so I can't reduce them.

```
time.reduce((sum, cur) => {
  const [mins, secs] = cur.split(':');
  let timer;
  timer = (parseFloat(mins * 60) + parseFloat(secs));
  console.log(timer);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there but the problem is that you are not returning anything from the reduce callback. The value return from that callback will be used as `sum` for the next iteration.

```js
const arr = ["5:43", "2:33", "3:45", "0:47", "5:21", "6:56", "3:46", "5:25", "3:14", "3:31", "5:59", "3:07", "11:29", "8:57", "5:49", "5:52", "5:50", "9:13", "11:51", "7:58", "4:40", "4:45", "6:46", "7:24", "7:12", "5:23", "3:34", "8:22", "5:17", "3:10", "4:43", "19:43", "0:47", "0:47", "3:14", "3:59", "2:43", "4:17", "6:56", "3:05", "2:06", "1:59", "1:49", "3:36", "7:10", "3:44", "3:44", "4:36", "3:16", "1:10", "6:10", "2:14", "3:44", "5:05", "6:03", "12:39", "1:56", "4:04"]

const total = arr.reduce((ac, a) => {
  let [min, secs] = a.split(':').map(Number);
  return ac + secs + (min * 60)
}, 0)

console.log(total)
```

Comment: You've used map method) It's ok, I've added Number straight to vars. Thank you very much!